# Invald characters at start of message from Solace-MQ

Tags: java, solace, solace-mq

We have an two Java applications that communicate with each other via solace-mq. Component-1 uses a JMS Publisher to write JSON messages to the queue. Component-2 is using a native Solace consumer to consume them.

The problem is, the message Component-2 receives has invalid characters at the start of the message before the JSON open curly braces. Why is that? Has anybody else experienced this issue?

FYI The client we are using is sol-jcsmp-7.1.2.230

Comment: Just wondering if you resolved this issue? I am facing the same problem when sending a TextMessage

Answer (score 2):

Old post here!  But wanted to correct Dishant's answer above in case people stumble onto this in the future.  He's correct with regards to where JMS text payloads are encoded within the Solace message by default (legacy, backwards-compatibility reasons): inside the old XML payload section, whose use is discouraged.  Almost every other Solace API only uses the binary payload section.  Sometimes special handling code (as above) in other APIs need to take this into account as the payload could be in either place.

HOWEVER!  The OP was asking about weird characters at the start of the payload, before the JSON `{` brace.  This is due to the original publisher (could be JMS or any other) of the data sending a structured TextMessage, and the consumer of the data treating the payload as a binary blob... which therefore sees some of those structure bytes.  For compatibility, the consumer needs to check the Type of message received (bytes, text, etc.) and decode the payload appropriately.

I spent some time recently writing a detailed post about it here: https://solace.community/discussion/3378/weird-chars-at-start-of-text-payload

Answer (score 0):

What type of JMS message are you sending and how are you setting the payload? Also how are you extracting the payload in the consumer app?

Depending on the type of message you are creating in your JMS app, when received via Solace native Java API the payload maybe encoded in a different part of the message. For a JMS `TextMessage` it will be in the XML content part of the message (unless you have the JMS connection factory setting `text-msg-xml-payload` to be set to false) and for a JMS `BytesMessage` it will be in the Binary part of the message.

To correctly extract the payload when exchanging messages between open APIs and protocols do the following in your message receive callback `XMLMessageLister.onReceive()` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(BytesXMLMessage msg) {
    String messagePayload = "";

    if(msg.hasContent()) {
        // XML content part
        byte[] contentBytes = new byte[msg.getContentLength()];
        msg.readContentBytes(contentBytes);
        messagePayload = new String(contentBytes);
    } else if(msg.hasAttachment()) {
        // Binary attachment part
        ByteBuffer buffer = msg.getAttachmentByteBuffer();
        messagePayload = new String(buffer.array());
    }

    // Do something with the messagePayload like 
    // convert the String back to a JSON object
    System.out.println("Message received: " + messagePayload);
}
```

Also see the following documentation: https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Creating-JMS-Compatible-Msgs.htm if sending from Solace native API to a JMS consumer app.